# Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I have five fields called:

1. Class_part1__c,  Field type: Formula (Text)
2. Class_part2__c,  Field type: Formula (Text)
3. Class_part3__c,  Field type: Formula (Text)
4. Class_part4__c,  Field type: Formula (Text)
5. Class_part5__c,  Field type: Formula (Text)

In one record, only one of these fields contains Content.
I want to set up a Process, checking each of these fields if there is Content or not, if there is than a field update should fill it into the field called:

1. Classification__c,   Field type: Text

[image]

All five steps are the same:

Class1 Content =  Class_part1__c Does not equal String "None"
TRUE: Acion Name "enter Class1 to Classification" Field: Classification__c Formula Class_part1__c
FALSE: Class2 Content =  Class_part2__c Does not equal String "None"...

The Process is Activated bot nothing happens. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by having "Content" that it has a value

Instead of having all of those steps:

1. Have **ONE** check that is

   - Records meeting criteria
   - Have for the criteria `Field NOT EQUAL to Global Constant Null`
   - Set the criteria to `OR` instead of and
2. then have it update your field